# I've written this code to find duplicates and it works fine:

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Cust_FirstName, Cust_LastName,Cust_PhoneNumber,Cust_Email
FROM tbl_Customer
GROUP BY Cust_FirstName,Cust_LastName,Cust_PhoneNumber,Cust_Email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The problem is, it's returning just one of the duplicate rows. Is it possible to return all the duplicate rows? I'm guessing it may have something to do with the 'GROUP BY' but

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
WITH g AS (
    SELECT Cust_FirstName, Cust_LastName,Cust_PhoneNumber,Cust_Email
    FROM tbl_Customer
    GROUP BY Cust_FirstName,Cust_LastName,Cust_PhoneNumber,Cust_Email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
)
SELECT c.* 
FROM tbl_Customer c
INNER JOIN g 
ON c.Cust_FirstName = g.CustFirstName
AND c.Cust_LastName = g.Cust_LastName
AND c.Cust_PhoneNumber = g.Cust_PhoneNumber
AND c.Cust_Email = g.Cust_Email
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using window functions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_FirstName, Cust_LastName, Cust_PhoneNumber, Cust_Email) as cnt
      FROM tbl_Customer c
     ) c
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt DESC,
         Cust_FirstName, Cust_LastName, Cust_PhoneNumber, Cust_Email;
```

Not only should this have better performance than a solution using `GROUP BY`/`JOIN`.  It also handles `NULL` values, so you will see duplicates where there are `NULL`s.  Of course, you can control the `NULL`s using a `WHERE` clause if you actually want to filter them out.